# Android 2.2 2.3 workaround for device-width media query

Tags: javascript, android, mobile-website, media-queries, mobile-webkit

I've observed a problem on Android 2.2 and 2.3 native browser where `device-width` CSS media query and `window.screen.width` both report sizes based on your webpage document and scaling applied.

*Example:* 1:1 scaling, 960px wide page will show proper device width (say, 320px)

*Example:* fit-screen scaling, 960px wide page, improperly reports 960px device width

So with appropriate viewport meta tag content it seems predictable.  However, in my case I cannot rely on the meta tag.  Does anyone use a workaround to get a reliable device width measurement in Android irrespective of viewport meta tag?  Other platforms do report this correctly across all scaling.

Ref:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11961

Answer (score 0):

window.outerWidth and window.outerHeight always report the browser pixels (ie screen resolution minus UI bars, typically 480x762 on a Galaxy S.)

You may then to throw in window.devicePixelRatio to calculate the virtual pixel width (320px).